# SQL Alias Column From Parent Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

To simplify the problem I have here are two tables:

subjects:

- id - INT
- device_id - varchar

reports:

- id
- created_on
- start_time
- end_time
- subject_ids - array of subject ids

I would like a postgres statement that would return to me all columns from the reports table and add an extra column of an array of device_id from the subject table based  on the array of subject_ids from the reports table.

The example is simpler than the total schema and so changing the schema is not an option here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to first `UNNEST()` your `subject_ids` so you get individual rows from your `reports` table for each `subject_id`. Then join to your `subjects` table and `ARRAY_AGG()` your `device_id`.

It will look something like:

```
SELECT r.id, ARRAY_AGG(s.device_id)
FROM (SELECT id, UNNEST(subject_ids) as subject_id FROM reports) r
   LEFT OUTER JOIN subjects s ON r.subject_id = s.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

[Here is a DBFiddle of this in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8943e8c607a060ecd5223290b65cfe35)

Comment: Just updated the fiddle to make it clear to see it working. Thanks https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e68c616a331bce9cdf97e21a122c185d